# random forest variable lengths differ

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification, regression, random-forest

I am trying to run RF using a feature as the response variable.  I am having trouble passing a string through a variable to be used as the response in RF.    First I try running RF on the string passed through a variable as the response and I am getting a "vector lengths differ error".  After this, I try just inputing the actual string(feature) as the response and it works fine.  Can you shed some light on why the variable lengths are differing?  Thanks.

```
> colnames(Data[1])
[1] "feature1"
> rf.file = randomForest(formula =colnames(Data[1])~ ., data = Data, proximity = T,      importance = T, ntree = 500, nodesize = 3)
Error in model.frame.default(formula = colnames(Data[1]) ~ .,  : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'feature1')

Enter a frame number, or 0 to exit   

1: randomForest(formula = colnames(Data[1]) ~ ., data = Data, proximity = T, importance = T, ntree = 500, nodesize = 3)
2: randomForest.formula(formula = colnames(Data[1]) ~ ., data = brainDataTrim, proximity = T, importance = T, ntree = 500, nodesize = 3)
3: eval(m, parent.frame())
4: eval(expr, envir, enclos)
5: model.frame(formula = colnames(Data[1]) ~ ., data = Data, na.action = function (object, ...) 
6: model.frame.default(formula = colnames(Data[1]) ~ ., data = Data, na.action = function (object, ...) 

Selection: 0



> rf.file = randomForest(formula =feature1~ ., data = Data, proximity = T,      importance = T, ntree = 500, nodesize = 3)
> rf.file

Call:
 randomForest(formula = feature1 ~ ., data = Data,      proximity = T, importance = T, ntree = 500, nodesize = 3) 
               Type of random forest: regression
                     Number of trees: 500
No. of variables tried at each split: 3

          Mean of squared residuals: 0.1536834
                    % Var explained: 34.21
>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are simply misunderstanding how formulas work. Basically, your first attempt isn't *supposed* to work.

Formulas should consist of names of variables, possibly simple functions of them. e.g.

```
var1 ~ var2
var1 ~ log(var2)
```

Note the lack of quotes. If you didn't quote it, it's not a string, its a symbol.

So, avoid raw strings, weird evaluation demands (like `Data[1]`, or any use of `$`) in your formulas. To *construct* a formula from strings, paste it together and then call `as.formula` on the resulting string.

Keep in mind that the whole point of a formula is that you have provided a *symbolic* representation of the model, and R will then go look for the specific columns you named in the data frame provided.

I think some functions will do the coercion of a string representation of a formula for you (e.g. `"var1 ~ var2"`), but I wouldn't count on, or expect it.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I see that paste can be used to construct strings for use in formulas and that way actually worked out.  Another way I found to do it was to use the formula(x,y) and call the coordinates in the actual data table to be used as the x,y coordinates: randomForest(Data[ ,-1], Data [, 1], proximity = T)